# elasticsearch check indices exist returns true on first run

Tags: node.js, docker, elasticsearch

I have a `docker-compose` running 2 containers, each with its own service, `node` and `elasticsearch`.

**app.js**

```
...
const isElasticReady = await elastic.checkConnection();
if (isElasticReady) {
    const elasticIndex = await elastic.esclient.indices.exists({index:elastic.index});
    if (!elasticIndex.body) {
        await elastic.createIndex(elastic.index);
        await elastic.setMapping();
        await data.populateDatabase();
    }
}
...
```

Whenever I run `docker-compose up`, `esclient.indices.exists` always returns `false`, even though the index already exists. As a result I always get thrown a `resource_already_exists_exception`.

The strange thing is that I am using `nodemon` for development, and whenever I make changes while development `esclient.indices.exists` will return `true`. So the problem only happens when I run `docker-compose up`. I suspect something is happening asynchronously, but I am not sure what.

***docker-compose.yml** - `depends_on` has been set.

```
version: '3.6'
services:
    api:
        image: nodeservice/node:10.15.3-alpine
        container_name: nodeservice
        build: .
        ports:
            - 3000:3000
        environment:
            - NODE_ENV=local
            - ES_HOST=elasticsearch
            - NODE_PORT=3000
            - ELASTIC_URL=http://elasticsearch:9200
        volumes:
            - .:/usr/src/app
            - /usr/src/app/node_modules
        command: npm run dev
        links:
            - elasticsearch
        depends_on: 
            - elasticsearch
        networks:
            - esnet
    elasticsearch:
        container_name:my_elasticsearch
        image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.0.1
        volumes:
            - esdata:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
        environment: 
            - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
            - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
            - discovery.type=single-node
        logging:
            driver: none
        ports:
            - 9300:9300
            - 9200:9200
        networks:
            - esnet
volumes:
    esdata:
networks:
    esnet:
```

Any hints?

Comment: Are you sure, that before the code is being executed, the cluster is completly up and ready (green)?

Comment: I would think so. I see the "Successfully connected" message before I see the error message thrown back at me.
`await esclient.cluster.health({});
console.log("Successfully connected to ElasticSearch");
`

Comment: How do you verified, that the node service is not executed before the elasticsearch service is started? Do you have any ordering in place within your container? Would you mind tho share your dockerfile? Btw, it.'s best practice to separate the services from each other in two single and use docker compose or at least container linking to connect them

Comment: changed my question to include my `docker-compose.yml`. :)